# react hook form: add multiple field arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to use `react-hook-form` for 2 array properties `list1` and `list2`

```
const data = {
    name: "asdasd",
    list1: [{ name: "prod1" }, { name: "prod2" }],
    list2: ["test", "test2"],
  };
```

The code is working with `list1`:

```
const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, trigger, setError, watch } =
    useForm({
      defaultValues: data,
    });

  const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "list1" });

  const submitData = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitData)}>
      <div>
        <input {...register("name")} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          Lines <button onClick={() => append({})}>+</button>
        </div>
        {fields.map((field, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={field.id}>
              <input
                {...register(`list1.${index}.name` as const)}
                defaultValue={field.name}
              />
              <button onClick={() => remove(index)}>-</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

However I got the error when declaring both `list1` and `list2`

```
const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "list1",
  });
  const fieldArray2 = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "list2",
  });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify: The code you posted above the error message does not match the code inside the error message

Comment: Yes it is working with 1 useFieldArray and failed when I add 2nd useFieldArray.

Comment: It looks like typescript detected the string "list1" to be a type rather than a normal string... I don't see any issue in your code...

Answer (score 3):

You must create two useFieldArray Hooks with different props

```
const { fields: fieldsList1,
        remove: removeList1, 
        append: appemdList1 } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "list1" });

const { fields: fieldsList2,
        remove: removeList2, 
        append: appemdList2 } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "list2" });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "list1",
  } as never);
  const fieldArray2 = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "list2",
  } as never);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `list2: ["test", "test2"]` is not the good data. It is working fine with a list of objects:

```
const data = {
    name: "asdasd",
    list1: [{ name: "prod1" }, { name: "prod2" }],
    list2: [{ name: "prod1" }, { name: "prod2" }],
  };
```

Comment: You are using field.name in your JSX, and string arrays don't have a name property

Comment: I havent setup anything to list2 yet. The error happens when just adding 2nd `useFielArray`

Comment: I don't understand... clearly list2 is already an array of strings in your code

Comment: Nah it is for list1. Didnt do anything with the UI yet for list2.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My form used this type:

```
interface Ingredient {
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  unit: string;
}

interface RecipeValues {
  ingredients: Ingredient[];
  recipeName: string;
  duration: number;
  instructions: string[];
```

And calling:

```
const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
  name: "instructions",
  control,
});
```

Would give me an error similar to yours:

```
Type '"instructions"' is not assignable to type '"ingredients"'.ts(2322)
fieldArray.d.ts(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'UseFieldArrayProps<RecipeValues, "ingredients", "id">'
```

I racked my head trying to understand the problem, even deleted the ingredients key from my interface, but to no avail.
I tried to bypass it by using `ingredients` as a name for the `instructions` field array, but then I couldn't append an item:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Ingredient> | Partial<Ingredient>[]'
```

That made me understand the problem (not sure why it exists, though)! For some reason, useFieldArray automatically used `Ingredient`, which is an interface and not a primitive. Because the `instructions` key's value **is** a primitive, I could use it. Beats me why.
Nevertheless, once I created an interface for the instruction key and used it:

```
interface Instruction {
  content: string;
}

interface RecipeValues {
  ingredients: Ingredient[];
  recipeName: string;
  duration: number;
  instructions: **Instruction**[];
}
```

It all worked perfectly well :)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it wants nested field names (`instructions.0.content`) instead of referencing them directly (`instructions.0`)

Answer (score 0):

I realise that I'm very late to this party but the problem is not that you simply have two arrays. Its that `useFieldArray` is of type `FieldArrayWithId<{your_data_object_class}, "list1", "id">`.

In other words the field array "list1" is based on your whole data object, not just the first array member. This is why, when you try to do your second useFieldArray declaration, you get that error, because it looks to the form that you are trying to assign list2 as a property of list1.

I'm still trying to figure out how to get useFieldArray to just base itself on part of the original data object, rather than the whole thing.

One way out is to break your form down into separate form components (one form for list1 and one form for list2), which might work for you (unfortunately, it won't work for me, i really need them together).